# Getting user's business name and country via PayPal APIs

Tags: paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

Our company has clients who have PayPal accounts. We also have their PayPal emails.

The issue is how to get client's business_name and country by providing its PayPal email?

Is it possible to make it using PayPal API?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you reviewed their [documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/overview/)?

Comment: @taco-タコス Yes, but I couldn't find any examples how to make it. I have reviewed their Identity API but seems it doesn't provides such solution.

Comment: For security reasons, most APIs only supply information related to the account a given access token is associated with. As such, I don't think you'll be able to get information about your clients' PayPal accounts without asking for access from them (the client) directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a user makes a payment ([Set up standard payments](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/set-up-standard-payments/)), you'll receive their shipping address country code as part of the v2/checkout/orders capture response.

If you need to the country of a PayPal account separately from such a payment capture's shipping address, then you might need to implement [Log in with PayPal](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/log-in-with-paypal/) requesting the scope `address`, and have the user log in.

However, the capture response might also have a "payer" object with the billing account country (which can be different from the shipping country in some cases).